# install nodes npm v1.0.1

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I need a separate npm version besides my installed v1.4.21

How do I install it on my Ubuntu 14.10, to install [this package](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast), that requires npm v1.0.1?

I tried [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755841/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-npm-using-nvm) but it already fails with `. ~/nvm/nvm.sh` because it installs in the current folder in `./node_modules/nvm/`

When I try

```
./node_modules/nvm/bin/nvm install 1.0.1
```

I get

```
~/.nvm/node-v1.0.1 doesn't exist, (need to downloaded first?) 1.0.1
```

How do I get npm v1.0.1 running?

Comment: You don't need v1.0.1.  That's the package version.  You can install it right now.

Comment: sure, I tried that first to just install it with the installed npm version, but that [doesn't work](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast/issues/3)

Comment: Read the error message.  Your path is wrong.

Comment: thx, i fixed it here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast/pull/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: I didnt need the old nvm version, I just had to start it from within the folder:

```
cd ./node_modules/webrtc-scalable-broadcast/
node ./server.js
```

see: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast/pull/4

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend removing all your current node and npm versions
[Uninstall Node.JS using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line)
 and then install nvm via these instructions:
http://www.wenincode.com/installing-node-jsnpm-without-sudo/

use curl:

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.12.1/install.sh | bash
```

or use wget:

```
$ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.12.
```

Once you've run either of those commands and NVM has finished downloading, run the following command:

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

Now NVM commands should be working in the terminal, try `$ nvm` to confirm the NVM command is working. If not, try restarting your terminal.

Once NVM is working you can install a version of node by using the following command:

```
$ nvm install [version-no]
```

To list the available versions, run this command:

```
$ nvm ls-remote
```

To install a version of node run:

```
$ nvm install <version no>
$ nvm install 0.10.29     //example
```

then when you want to use a specific version of node use

```
nvm use <version no>
```

Its the easiest way to use node imo and removes the need for sudo too which can cause issues.