# NVM cannot load default node with default alias set

Tags: node.js, sublimetext, zsh, oh-my-zsh, nvm

My problem is almost the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585261/nvm-keeps-forgetting-node-in-new-terminal-session) but i already set the default alias.

Once i open a new console `nvm` does not load the default node, this problem is also present with some SublimeText3 plugins (eslint, jscs for example).

The only way to make it work is to add `nvm use default` after loading `nvm` but i thik i am doing something wrong.

*How can i make it work without the hack?*

---

**My configuration**

- brew 0.9.5
- nvm 0.26.0 (installed using brew)
- zsh (with oh-my-zsh)

I have `nvm` sourced in **`.zshenv`** with th following config:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
# nvm use default # <-- remove comment to make node available
```

`nvm` is configured as follows (result of the command `nvm ls`):

```
iojs-v3.0.0
v0.12.7
default -> iojs (-> iojs-v3.0.0)
node -> stable (-> v0.12.7) (default)
stable -> 0.12 (-> v0.12.7) (default)
iojs -> iojs-v3.0 (-> iojs-v3.0.0) (default)
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh-my-zsh includes a nvm plugin, I would recommend you to use it, but first

1. remove from your .zshenv all changes
2. remove the nvm install with brew uninstall
3. install nvm using curl (official installation): `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.26.0/install.sh | bash`
   this wont configure your profile to use it yet.
4. edit the file at your users home called .zshrc finding the plugins section and there include `nvm` save it and source your profile or close and open again your terminal.
5. use nvm to install a node version and set the default alias

Comment: Ok, it worked. The key point here seems to be the "**4** Adding the `nvm` plugin". I also moved the `nvm` activation lines added by the script from `.zshrc` to `.zshenv`.

Comment: @Volox After moving those lines to `.zshenv` did your shell become crazy slow? I did exactly the same, but my shell become super slow.

Comment: @RuiAfonsoPereira no, as far as i can tell there is no visible difference in speed.

Answer (score 0):

In oh-my-zsh, you can go to `/etc` then use `nano ~/.zshrc`, find export `PATH=$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v16.5.0/bin/:$PATH` change node version what you want