# error eslint@5.6.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. when trying to create-react-app

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I am trying to create a React App and I am getting the following error in my console.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.10.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > eslint > file-entry-cache > flat-cache > circular-   json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error eslint@5.6.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.    Expected version "^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0". Got "9.5.0"
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this     command.

Aborting installation.
yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd      /Volumes/server2/Desktop/JavaScript/birdcage has failed.

  Deleting generated file... package.json
  Deleting birdcage / from /Volumes/server2/Desktop/JavaScript
  Done.
```

I have tried `brew upgrade node` but that didn't seem to work.  Any ideas on how this can be fixed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

One of the temporally fix is to run `yarn install --ignore-engines`

Comment: Great suggestion! Where can I set the engine flag? I dont have one set in the eslint.rc file, so it must got to a default.

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same issue, try to add "--use-npm" at the end of create react app commend.

**`create-react-app appname --use-npm`**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, simply doing this solved the problem:

```
 npm install node@latest
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, try it:

```
yarn config set ignore-engines true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall yarn and install it via npm.

1. npm i create-react-app -g
2. create-react-app yourappname
   Make sure that node is installed!

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed node and updated xcode developer tools. Also, re-installed React on that computer which is running Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nvm is installed, use it to see which version of node you're using, then use it to change to a later version.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the version with `nvm use <version>` and then try again

Answer (score 0):

In my Ubuntu 18.04 had a native version from the OS installed that not listed by NVM.

I removed it and then I ran:

Firstly run, `nvm install 14.5.0`
then run,  `nvm use 14.5.0`

And the installation completed properly.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue when i was adding router plugin to vue-cli with npx and yarn as well..
In pyhton virtual environment i have updated node version from 8.x.x to 16.x.x and used command nvm use 16.x.x but still problem persists .. i was actually executing command as root .. so nvm is using node version as 8.x.x only ..

after long time i realised executing command with sudo was the issue and then executed as a normal user...

this solution worked for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

As the warning said, I updated node via nvm to the version required. For me having the latest node lts version was enough.

`nvm install "lts/*" --reinstall-packages-from="$(nvm current)"`

But even after upgrading node, yarn still gave the error.

The problem was npm was still executed from the old `.bin` path of previous node version. `nvm` also installs latest version of `npm` in respective local `.bin` folder for the node version installed.

I used the following commands then,

`nvm install-latest-npm`: Attempt to upgrade to the latest working npm on the current node version

`nvm install --latest-npm`: After installing, attempt to upgrade to the latest working npm on the given node version

After this, it worked properly.

Reference:
[How can I change the version of npm using nvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755841/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-npm-using-nvm)