# How to update the Node version to 14 in Mac?

Tags: node.js

Already I have installed the Node version 8.
And, I'm using this version for one project.

I need to install Node version 8 for the new project without changing the version to 8.

How to update using command?

Please help with this.

Comment: So, do you want to run multiple node versions in parallel?
Side note: Version 8 is heavily outdated and way out of support, I would strongly recommend to not use it, if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run two different nodejs applications with two different node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669518/how-to-run-two-different-nodejs-applications-with-two-different-node-version)

Comment: You can take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-node-js-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os

Answer (score 0):

Try `nvm` (Node Version Manager)

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm