# npm install fails after upgrading my node version

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, npm, sass

I'm using Node `v16.14.0` and cannot install Sass. Here is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: How are you using NPM 3 with Node 16?

Comment: When I switched to node version 14.18.3, I was able to install sass

Comment: Using nvm when I switch to v16.14.0, the npm version also changes to 3. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would strongly recommend upgrading npm to the latest version. This isn't a node issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the version of npm using nvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755841/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-npm-using-nvm)

Answer (score 4):

You have NPM `v3.10.10` with Node `v16.14.0`, where the default NPM is `v8.3.1` for that Node version. It's not about Sass, I would suggest you to upgrade your NPM version:

```
npm i -g npm
```