# Doesn't install NPM when I install a new Node version using NVM

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

Whenever I update Node with `nvm`, `npm` is no longer available.

1. `nvm install 14.19.3` > It says it's also downloading and installing npm.
2. `npm` > Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
3. Looking in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.19.3`, the subfolder `node_modules` is empty. It doesn't seem to have installed npm along with nvm, even though there was no error upon `nvm install 14.19.3`.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24721903) I understand the cause of a problem like this generally is a conflict in the environment variables of the OS (I'm using VSC on a Windows 10 machine).

But I can't find anything wrong there: PATH includes `NVM_HOME` and `NVM_SYMLINK`, which respectively point to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\nvm` and `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

How can I get this new version of Node to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to update my [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/) version (from 1.1.7 to 1.1.9).

After this I uninstalled the Node version and installed it again with the new nvm version. Now it did install NPM along with Node.

`nvm use 14.20.0` (the new Node version I installed) gave an error however:

```
exit status 5: Access is denied.
```

Running the terminal / Visual Studio Code with administrator privilages solved this issue and I was able to successfully switch Node versions.

Comment: Sweet! Glad you've got that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the `NVM_SYMLINK` point to `%AppData%\npm` or `C:\Users\Username\AppData\npm`?

Have you tried to: `nvm install-latest-npm` or `nvm install --latest-npm`?

Also check it out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755841/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-npm-using-nvm) as it may help.

Comment: I think `NVM_SYMLINK` is correct, especially since `npm` does work for the already installed Node versions. The different Node versions are located in subfolders inside ``C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\`` . The Node versions for which `npm` works has for example ``...\nvm\9.8.0\node_modules\`` with `npm` and nodemon etc. inside that folder. But for newly installed Node versions that `node_modules` folder, while it does exist, is empty.

Comment: `nvm install --latest-npm` returns `Node.js vlatest-npm.0.0 is only available in 32-bit`.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution was to just pick another Node version. I am not sure for a particular reason but I used via **NVM** at least 4 different version and they are all fine. Only the following version **14.17.0** seems buggy.