# How can I change to Node.js version 112.6.0 using nvm?

Tags: reverse-engineering

How can I change to Node.js version 112.6.0 using nvm? For Windows 10, I am getting a problem to solve.

```
node --version 16.13.1
```

Convert to 12.6.0.

Comment: Perhaps *[How can I change the version of npm using nvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755841/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-npm-using-nvm)*?

Comment: Re *"version 112.6.0"*: Don't you mean *"version 12.6.0"*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the version of npm using nvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755841/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-npm-using-nvm)