# How to use nvm version 8 in node 14

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to use npm version 8 in node version 14.
I installed version 8 by `npm i -g npm@8`, but still it uses old one which is `npm -v 6.14.17`.

Can someone help me with how I can have npm version `8` while keeping the node version `14`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `nvm` instead of `npm`. Package manager vs version manger I think.

```
nvm install 8.10.0

nvm use 8.10.0
```

Can also check out this answer. Looks on par with what you’re asking.

[How can I change the version of npm using nvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755841/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-npm-using-nvm)